# What is a good way to add UIPageViewController to parent UIViewController without considering status bar height?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I have a `UIViewController`, with its top component consists of a horizontal `UICollectionView` ([MenuTabsView.swift](https://github.com/penumutchuprasad/PageViewControllerWithTabs/blob/master/PageViewControllerWithTabs/MenuTabsView.swift))

[image]

Now, I  would like to add a `UIPageViewController`, just below the MenuTabsView.

I have tried the following few approaches.

---

### Programatically without taking status bar height into consideration

```
func presentPageVCOnView() {
    
    self.pageController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageControllerVC") as! PageControllerVC
    self.pageController.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: menuBarView.frame.maxY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - menuBarView.frame.maxY)
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageController.view)
    self.pageController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    
}
```

Here's the outcome.

[image]

From 1st glance, it seems that `UIPageViewController`'s view need to offset by Y status bar distance. (But why?)

---

### Programatically by taking status bar height into consideration

```
func presentPageVCOnView() {
    let statusBarHeight = CGFloat(20.0)
    
    self.pageController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageControllerVC") as! PageControllerVC
    self.pageController.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: menuBarView.frame.maxY + statusBarHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - menuBarView.frame.maxY - statusBarHeight)
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageController.view)
    self.pageController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Now, it looks way better.

[image]

---

### Use container view without status bar offset

But, I don't feel comfortable, on why we need to manually consider status bar height, during programatically way. I was thinking, maybe I can add a `ContainerView` to `UIViewController`, and "attach" the `UIPageViewController`'s view to it?

**(I am not sure why during adding Container View to storyboard, an additional `UIViewController` will be added along. Anyhow, I just manually delete the additional `UIViewController`)**

[image]

[image]

Then, I use the following code to "attach" the `UIPageViewController`'s view to new container view.

```
func presentPageVCOnView() {

    self.pageController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageControllerVC") as! PageControllerVC
    self.pageController.view.frame = containerView.frame
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageController.view)
    self.pageController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

But, the outcome is not what as expected. Y offset still happen!!!

[image]

---

### Use container view with status bar offset

I try to make sure, there are space of 20, between the top component `MenuTabsViews` and `UIPageViewController`'s view.

[image]

[image]

---

I was wondering, is there any good practice/ solution, to ensure we can add `UIPageViewController`'s view below another component, without affecting by status bar height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all without any code -- it just takes an understanding of how `UIContainerView` works.

There's no real `UIContainerView` class... it is an automated way of adding a child view controller via Storyboard / Interface Builder. When you add a `UIContainerView`, IB automatically creates a "default" view controller connected to the container view with an `Embed` segue. You can ***change*** that default controller.

Here's step-by-step (images are large, so you'll probably want to click them to see the details)...

Start with a fresh `UIViewController`:

[image]

Add your "Menu Bar View" - I have it constrained Top/Leading/Trailing to safe-area, Height of 60:

[image]

Drag a `UIContainerView` onto the view - note that it creates a default view controller *at the current size of the container view*. Also note that it shows a segue. If you inspect that segue, you'll see it is an `Embed` segue:

[image]

Constrain the Top of the container view to the Bottom of your Menu Bar View, and Leading/Trailing/Bottom to safe-area. Notice that the size of the embedded view controller automatically takes the new size of the container view:

[image]

Select that default controller... and delete it:

[image]

Drag a new `UIPageViewController` onto your Storyboard and set its Custom Class to `PageControllerVC`:

[image]

Now, Ctrl-Click-Drag from the Container view to the newly added page view controller. When you release the mouse button, select `Embed` from the popup:

[image]

You now have an `Embed` segue from the container view to your page view controller. Notice that it automatically adjusted its size to match the container view size:

[image]

Since the Menu Bar View top is constrained to the safe-area, it will behave as expected.

Since the container view top is constrained to the bottom of the Menu Bar View, it will stay there, and should give you what you want.

No Code Needed :)

---

**Edit**

The most likely reason you ran into trouble with loading via code is with you frame setting.

If you try to set frames in `viewDidLoad()`, for example, auto-layout has not configured the rest of the view hierarchy... so framing will not be what you expect.

You're much better off using auto-layout / constraints, rather than setting explicit frames anyway.

Here is how I would do it from code (assumes you have your "Menu Bar View" connected via `@IBOutlet`):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var menuBarView: UIView!
    
    var pageControllerVC: PageControllerVC?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageControllerVC") as? PageControllerVC else {
            fatalError("Could not instantiate PageControllerVC!!!")
        }
        guard let v = vc.view else {
            fatalError("loaded PageControllerVC had no view ????")
        }
        addChild(vc)
        view.addSubview(v)

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuBarView.bottomAnchor),
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        vc.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        self.pageControllerVC = vc

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Wow! Appreciate a lot for teaching me this useful technique. But, is there any way for me, to create an IBOutlet for page view controller? Previously, in my view controller, I use code to create the page view controller, and hold a member variable for that. But right now, all thing are being done via storyboard. How can I obtain a reference to that page view controller? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to ctrl + click + drag from page view controller storyboard to view controller source code, but nothing happen. If I ctrl + click + drag from container view, the suggested member variable is UIView.

Comment: I guess I found some resources - https://medium.com/@superpeteblaze/ios-swift-tip-getting-references-to-container-child-view-controllers-653fe58e6f5e Will try it out right away.

Comment: I try the `Embed` method. It works flawlessly. Thank you! But may I know, why `self.pageController.view.frame = self.containerView.frame` doesn't work, if we intent to do it programatically? In our storyboard, we have already ensure the containerView's constraints are relative to safe area and the top component.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove safeArea pinning for pageVC.
Safe area includes status bar and iPhone 11+ top space

```
tabBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
// to this
tabBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor)
```

And in storyboards change Safe Area to SuperView
[image]

Comment: Sorry. I do not get your point. Can you elaborate more? Currently, the position of tabBar (MenuTabsViews) is correct. In my last screenshot, you can see the container view (holding pageVC's view) is align relative to tabBar. Only the bottom of container view is align relative to safe area.

Comment: You shouldn't change frames at all while you use constraints, and you shouldn't check for status bar in code. Instead use only constraints from storyboard.
   `self.pageController.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: menuBarView.frame.maxY + statusBarHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - menuBarView.frame.maxY - statusBarHeight)`
Remove all frame changes in your code and leave constraints
And if you want something to go under status bar, remove safeArea. Your top constraints is aligned to safeArea